# C# DLL Import with VC++

Tags: c#, visual-c++, dll

I am new to Visual Studio 2010,

I have the DLL written with C# , and it is working with VB.NET , Now I want to use it with VC++, Can you help me ?

Comment: Which VC++? Managed or native?

Comment: http://1code.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/60353#994441

Answer (score 2):

If you are planning on using .NET extensions in your VC++ project, you just need to add a reference to your C# DLL in your VC++ project.

If you're planning to use pure C++, you'll need to change your C# DLL to be COM-Visible, and generate a typelib that you'll import in your C++ project.

Answer (score 1):

You can access functions from native DLL (written in C++) from .NET using PInvoke. To use managed DLL from native code (eg. call C# method from C++ code) you have to wrap managed code in COM component and use that COM object from C++

Answer (score 0):

Going the other way is easy using P/invoke. Calling managed code from unmanaged is tricker. One good option is COM, but there is an alternative. Robert Giesecke has published an [excellent project](https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports) that allows you to expose managed methods as unmanaged DLL exports.

It's very simple to use. You simply download the Visual Studio template, create a project based on that, add your code, and mark exports with the `DllExport` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can create Manager C++ DLL that will reference and implement all or custom objects from C# DLL.
After than you can create dllexport methods in your MCPP DLL.
And then you can access C# DLL thru MCPP DLL using LoadLibrary(...)/GetProcAddress(...) methods.
Example:

```
    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

    __declspec(dllexport) LPVOID GetPluginInterface()
    {
        return (IWithExecuteCommandMethod*)&theApp;
    }
    bool CClass::ExecuteCommand()
    {
        if(Threading::Thread::CurrentThread->TrySetApartmentState(System::Threading::ApartmentState::STA))
        {
            Flatbed::SomeDialog ^pDialog=gcnew Flatbed::SomeDialog();
            pDialog->ShowDialog();
        }
        else
        {
            Threading::Thread ^pDialog=gcnew Threading::Thread(gcnew Threading::ThreadStart(ThreadProc));
            pDialog->SetApartmentState(Threading::ApartmentState::STA);
            pDialog->Start();
        }

        return false;
    }
```